# Question about rank and consistent system..

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an  $m\times n$ matrix with entries in $Z_{p}.$ Any
consistent system of linear equation with cofficient matrix $A$ has exactly $%
p^{n-rank\left( A\right) }$ solution over $Z_{p}.$

$n=$variables

number of free variables=$n-$rank$\left( A\right) $

Comment: Your title is "Question about..." but I do not see a question, certainly not an explicit one. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i want to solve this ....Let A be an m×n matrix with entries in Zp. Any consistent system of linear equation with coefficient matrix A has exactly pn−rank(A) solution over Zp.

n=variables

number of free variables=n−rank(A)

Comment: Again, the term "solve" implies that a question has been asked.  There is no question here, only a statement. Although you have not said not explicitly, it seems that you would like to **prove** the statement. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. you are right respected sir.

Answer (score 0):

Note that whenever the system $Ax = b$ is consistent, its solution can be written in the following form. If we select a "particular solution" $x_p$ of $Ax = b$, then every solution to $Ax = b$ can be written in the form $x = x_p + x_h$ where $x_h$ is a solution to the "homogenous problem" $Ax = 0$.

Now, note that the "solutions to the homogeneous problem" are the elements of $\ker(A)$ (AKA the null space of $A$).  In other words, the number of solutions to $Ax = b$ is equal to the number of elements in $\ker(A)$, and this number is determined by the dimension of the subspace $\ker(A)$.  Apply the rank-nullity theorem.